# Zero padding DFT intuition

Tags: dft, dtft, zero-padding

I'm trying to grasp some intuition about why zero-padding the time domain sequence $x[n]$ interpolates the frequency domain bins of the $DFT\{x[n]\} = X[k]$ and how does this relate to the $DTFT$ of $x[n]$.

Let's say we have $N$ point signal $x[n]$ and we pad it with 0's in the time domain as usual.
So, as we append more and more zeros to $x[n]$ and perform the $DFT$, we know that $DFT$ makes the assumption that the signal is periodic, hence the period tends to infinity, hence we get frequency samples (more and more and padding increaes) of the $N$ point $DTFT$ applied to the original $x[n]$ ?

I'd love some insights and intution please.
Thanks

Comment: [Related](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/71434/50076)

Comment: Please also see this post detailing an intuitive view of the DTFT vs DFT which gives insight into how zero padding approximates the DTFT: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/73781/does-ifft-of-higher-order-equal-upsampling-signal/73784#73784

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say a discrete signal $x(n)$ and its Z-transform $X(z)$, discrete time Fourier transform $X(e^{j\omega})$, and discrete Fourier transform $X(k)$. The relationships between DFT and ZT / DTFT are respectively:

$$
X(k) = X(z)|_{z=e^{j2\pi k/N}} \tag{1.1}
$$

$$
X(k) = X(e^{j\omega})|_{\omega=2\pi k/N} \tag{1.2}
$$

Since the original signal $x(n)$ can be perfectly reconstructed by IDFT, yes you can certainly obtain DTFT from DFT. However, you can't get DTFT by padding zeros as long as possible but by a technique called frequency domain interpolation. First is reconstruction of ZT from DFT:

$$
X(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x(n)z^{-n}=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\Big[\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}X(k)W_N^{-nk} \Big]z^{-n} \\ =  \frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}X(k)\Big[ \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}W_N^{-nk}z^{-n} \Big] \\ = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}X(k)\frac{1-W_N^{-Nk}z^{-N}}{1-W_N^{-k}z^{-1}} = \frac{1-z^{-N}}{N} \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\frac{X(k)}{1-W_N^{-k}z^{-1}} \tag{2}
$$

where $W_N^{nk} = e^{j\frac{2\pi}{N}nk}$. Define the interpolation function

$$\varPhi_k(z) = \frac{1}{N}\frac{1-z^{-N}}{1-W_N^{-k}z^{-1}} = \frac{z^N-1}{Nz^{N-1}(z-W_N^{-k})} \tag{3}$$

and $X(z)$ can be written as

$$
X(z) = \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}X(k)\varPhi_k(z) \tag{4}
$$

Now let $z = e^{j\omega}$ we can derive that

$$
X(e^{j\omega}) = \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}X(k)\varPhi_k(e^{j\omega}) \tag{5}
$$

and the interpolation function

$$
\varPhi_k(e^{j\omega}) = \frac{1-e^{-j\omega N}}{N(1-W_N^{-k}e^{-j\omega})} = \frac{1-e^{-j\omega N}}{N(1-e^{-j(\omega-2\pi k/N)})}\\ = \frac{1}{N}\frac{\sin(N\omega/2)}{\sin\big[(\omega-2\pi k/N)/2\big]} e^{-j[\omega(N-1)/2 + k\pi/N]} \\
=\frac{1}{N}\frac{\sin(N\omega/2)}{\sin\big[(\omega-2\pi k/N)/2\big]} e^{jk\pi(N-1)/N} e^{-j(N-1)\omega/2} \tag{6}
$$

Let's write it in a more convinient form as

$$
\varPhi_k(e^{j\omega}) = \varPhi(\omega - 2\pi k/N) \tag{7}
$$

where $\varPhi(\omega)$ is the Fourier transform of a $N$-point rectangle window divided by $N$

$$
\varPhi(\omega) = \frac{1}{N} \frac{\sin(\omega N/2)}{\sin(\omega/2)} e^{-j(N-1)\omega/2} \tag{8}
$$

Finally, we get the equation of reconstructing DTFT by interpolating DFT

$$
X(e^{j\omega}) = \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}X(k)\varPhi(\omega-2\pi k/N) \tag{9}
$$

Comment: 1) So basicaly you are saying that for finite length sequence $x[n]$, there is an interpolation such that I can get the DTFT out of the DFT bins?
2) But how does this relate to zero padding? Isn't the zero padding sort of interpolation on its own?

Comment: 1) Yes, but recall the definition of DTFT, the summation extends from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. Mathematically, the interpolation can only reconstruct **truncated DTFT**. 2) And yes, the zero padding is a sort of interpolation approaching to DTFT, but the result it returns is still **DFT** (it's $X(k)$ not $X(e^{j\omega})$).